# Proving that the indicator function is a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that I have that $X = \mathbb{1}_{A}$ is the indicator of some event $A \in \mathcal{F}$. I would like to show that $X$ is a random variable.

My proof is that $X^{-1}(B)$, where $B$ is the Borel Set, must be $A$ or $A^{C}$, since the indicator variable must take either $1$ or $0$, when $\omega \in A$ and $\omega \in A^{C}$, respectively.

However, it appears that $X^{-1}(B)$ must be either $\emptyset$ or $\Omega$ as well. This is not clear to me why. If $X(\omega)$ can only take two values, $1$ or $0$, how can it take on $\emptyset$ or $\Omega$ as well? Would it even make sense to define $X(\emptyset)$ or $X(\Omega)$?

Comment: Determine $X^{-1}(B)$ for the following cases: 1) 0,1 is in B, 2) 0 is in B but 1 isn't, 3) 1 is in B but 0 isn't, 4) neither 0 nor 1 is in B.

Comment: Thanks, I see, so 1) corresponds to $\Omega$, 2) to $A^{C}$, 3) to $A$, and 4) to $\emptyset$? However, I thought that $X^{-1}(B)$ was defined formally as $X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B\}$. How can we have the empty set if the set is defined for $\omega \in \Omega$? Does it then imply that $\emptyset \in \Omega$?

Comment: You might want to compute $X^{-1}(B)$ for $B=[2,5]$ and for $B=[-4,3]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definitions
$$\mathsf 1_A^{-1}(B) = \{\omega\in\Omega: \mathsf 1_A(\omega)\in B\} $$
and $$\mathsf 1_A(\omega) = \begin{cases}1,& \omega\in A\\0,&\omega\notin A,\end{cases} $$
we see that 
$$
\mathsf 1_A^{-1}(B) = 
\begin{cases}
\varnothing,& 0\notin B,1\notin B\\
A^c,& 0\in B,1\notin B\\
A,& 0\notin B,1\in B\\
\Omega,& 0\in B,1\in B.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows then that $A$ is a random variable.

Comment: Why is the empty set an element of $\mathsf 1_A(\omega)\in B$ when it is specifically defined as being elements of $\Omega$?

Comment: @user123276 What is $$\large\mathsf 1_A^{-1}(\{2\})\ ? $$

Comment: I see, so basically according to axiomatic set theory the empty set is always contained in any set? Thanks!